# Angular How Can I Assign Null Value to Input on Date Picker

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Here is my code. I have a date picker where it shows a certain date for a property in my app. I want the date picker to show that date only if, `IsPrimerExists` is `true`. If it's not true, I want it to be null. Right now, the date picker is null for both conditions. What should I fix to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="!productionValue1">
    <mat-label>{{'İmalat Tarihi(' + Country1 +' '+Market1+')'}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="filterWeekend" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="countryDate1"
        name="countryDate1">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
productionOrder: IProductionOrder = {};
constructor() {
        if (_dialogRef.id != "ProductionOrder") {
            this.productForms = _data;
            if (this.productForms && this.productForms.length > 0) {
                this.totalProducedAmount = this.productForms[0].TargetQuantity;
            }
            let i = 0;
            this.productForms.forEach((x) => {
                if (i == 0) {
                    this.countryCheck1 = x.IsPeriod;
                    this.CountryVisible1 = true;
                    this.Country1 = x.GeoType.Name; 
                    this.Market1 = x.MarketType.Name;
                    this.previousCheck1 = x.IsPreviousMonth;
                    this.productionValue1 =
                        _dialogRef.id == "ProductForm" ? true : false;
                        if(this.productionOrder.IsPrimerExists){
                            this.countryDate1 = x.ProductionDate;
                        }
                                else{
                                    this.countryDate1 = null;
                                }
                }
            i++
}
```

IProductionOrder:

```
IsPrimerExists?: boolean;
```

[image]

Comment: As any input with [(ngModel)]: `this.countryDate1=null`. NOTE: Remember that to asign a value you need give a Javastring Date object. NOTE2 the type of your variable should be "any":`countryDate:any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formControl defined and in your input.

Like this:

```
<input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="filterWeekend" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="countryDate1"
    name="countryDate1">
```

And TS change to this:

```
this.countryDate1 = new Date(x.ProductionDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, but changing the HTML like made date picker disappear.

Comment: what the type of x.ProductionDate?? is this a string date??

Comment: It's of type `Date`

Comment: Okay . Then you don't need to do this [(ngModel)]="countryDate1.value" try [(ngModel)]="countryDate1" this only.  and this.countryDate1 = new Date(x.ProductionDate); Remove  new Date as its already Date. just use x.ProductionDate.   And also remove formControlName="countryDate1"

Comment: Edited in StackBlitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-38yxau?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.component.html